# How to change max open files limit(s) for spring-boot init.d service

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, debian, init.d

Trying to change default open file limit value for **spring-boot** application (in Debian based system), which is started as **init** (System V) script, but I have difficulties finding a solution:

1. General recommendation is to add `ulimit -n` line to /etc/init.d/. Not possible, since in spring-boot case  it's just a symlink to jar file.
2. spring-boot itself does not provide environment property or any convenient mechanism to do that.
3. `/etc/security/limits.conf` is not a solution either (does not effect daemons started during init)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not a spring-boot expert, but the (awesome) fact that you **can** simply create a symlink should not mean that you have to do it. Simple init script like this should do:

```
[root@localhost app]# cat /etc/init.d/myapp
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n 50001
/var/myapp/myapp.jar $1
```